# Is GLhalf a float point type or integer?

Tags: opengl

Table 2.2 in opengl specification says GLhalf is a 16 bit floating point scalar but in the header file glext.h it is defined as

```
typedef unsigned short GLhalf;
```

That means it's an integer type. Which one is right?

Comment: That's not what the spec is saying. The text is "Half-precision floating-point value **encoded in an unsigned scalar**".

Comment: @BDL: This is not a duplicate of that question. That question is about the `GL_HALF_FLOAT` enumerator; this is about the C or C++ data type you might use to fill in data consumed by things using that enumerator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the GPU a GLhalf is a 16 bit floating point scalar number, and will be added / multiplied / etc in that format.

On the CPU, many C compilers do not have a 16 bit floating point type. So the unsigned short definition is there to tell the C compiler that each value will take up 16 bits in memory.

Unfortunately this means the C compiler will also let you add / multiply / etc/ these values, which will totally screw them up because the CPU will perform 16 bit integer arithmetic on them. So don't do that. Don't even write "foo = 2"

You can get half-precision floating point libraries for C, and some C compilers do support 16 bit floats. You could use one of those if you want to do CPU operations on GLhalf.

Comment: Care to share one of those libraries that can create 16-bit floats? I hear operations on half precision numbers are done faster than those on single precision ones so it would improve performance eh?

Comment: Have not used one myself, so no recommendation. It almost certainly won't be faster on your CPU because the format will be emulated, so require multiple CPU instructions per operation.

Comment: But it would be faster on GPU, perhaps